# Jquery like .attr("data-iconpos","...") has no effect rendering page

Tags: jquery-mobile, attr

Changing an element with Jquery like  .attr("data-iconpos","...") is indeed performed, as can be seen inspecting the element.
However, it has no effect on the page rendering, which puzzles me (I was expecting the behaviour described in http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html).
Tested with :

- Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m
- Firefox 34.0.5
- IE 11.0.9600

Why is that ? (thanks for alternative solution, still my question is **why does page rendering fails ?** : I am interested to know if I missed something about Jquery).
I made a code sample available at http://akelai.fr/iconpos.html

Here is the code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test iconpos</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" width="device-width" content="initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).resize(function() {
        windowResize();
      });

      function windowResize() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 900) {
          $("#me").attr("data-iconpos", "left");
        } else {
          $("#me").attr("data-iconpos", "right");
        }
      }
    }); //
  </script>
</head>

<body id="theBody">
  <div data-role="page" id="board" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="horizontal">
      <h1>test changing iconpos</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-btn">
      <input type="button" id="me" data-icon="grid" value="Is icon on my left (width < 900px) or my right (width > 900px)">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the class of your button:

```
    if (width < 900) {
      $("#me").removeClass("ui-btn-icon-right").addClass("ui-btn-icon-left");
    } else {
      $("#me").removeClass("ui-btn-icon-left").addClass("ui-btn-icon-right");
    }
```

UPDATE: as @Tasos noticed, it must be done on the parent instead of the button itself:

```
    if (width < 900) {
      $("#me").parent().removeClass("ui-btn-icon-right").addClass("ui-btn-icon-left");
    } else {
      $("#me").parent().removeClass("ui-btn-icon-left").addClass("ui-btn-icon-right");
    }
```

UPDATE 2: A third, simpler option:

```
    if (width < 900) {
      $("#me").button("option", "iconpos", "left");
    } else {
      $("#me").button("option", "iconpos", "right");
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't work with input buttons as it has the (::after) in the CSS-- http://jsfiddle.net/8xowotg6/ . i think anyway :)

Comment: @Tasos and @Maurice Perry :  Thanks guy , your alternative solutions will be helpful for me (I'll use the "option" described by Maurice).  Still my question was and remain : "**Why page rendering fails ?**". Is there something I missed with this `.attr` methode ? Or is there some kind of conflict with Mobile / Ui / Touch-punch `libraries ? (-- this is why i left these libs in my code snippet).

Comment: @gerard Yes Jquery UI and JQM dont mix well, i was going to mention that to you yesterday but i thought you knew something i did not. It will in the future as they will mix the two together but for now its not advised.

Comment: I'm using jquery-ui and touch-punch in one of my projects, I've had a few issues, but I don't recall any rendering issue.

Comment: @Tasos : I removed the jquery-ui lib; behaviour is same.  I made a new demo file : http://akelai.fr/iconpos2.html

Comment: you have this code ($(window).resize(function() {
     windowResize();
    });
    function windowResize() {
     var width = $(window).width();
     if (width < 800) {
      $("#me").attr("data-iconpos", "left"); // does set the attribute, however it has no effect ???
     } else {
      $("#me").attr("data-iconpos", "right"); // does set the attribute, however it has no effect ???
     }
    })  use my code for testing